SVA assertion with local counter in it. Its not behaving as intended
I want to write an sva with a local counter delay. Im getting a right parenthesis error in the consequent part when i added 1'b1. I added that because i only wanted to decrement the local counter when signal_b was low and I didnt want it to fail when signal_b was going high through the simulation.
Property delay_sva

  int delay;

(signal_a,delay=500) |-> (1'b1 || (delay>0 && signal_b==0, delay=delay-1))[*0:$] ##1 signal_c ##0 (delay>0);

enddproperty


Please [edit] your question to include the system and/or programming language you are using.
